# react-router sidebar example understanding

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I've tried to use the react-router sidebar example: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/sidebar

```
    const routes = [
    {
        path: '/',
        exact: true,
        sidebar: () => <div>home!</div>,
        main: () => <h2>Home</h2>
    },
    {
        path: '/bubblegum',
        sidebar: () => <div>bubblegum!</div>,
        main: () => <App />
    },
    {
        path: '/shoelaces',
        sidebar: () => <div>shoelaces!</div>,
        main: () => <Felix />
    },
    {
        path: '/processes',
        sidebar: () => <div>shoelaces!</div>,
        main: () => <Processes />
    }
]

ReactDOM.render((
    <Router history={hashHistory}>
        <div>
            <div style={{display: 'flex'}}>
                <div style={{
                    padding: '10px',
                    width: '40%',
                    background: '#f0f0f0'
                }}>
                    <ul style={{listStyleType: 'none', padding: 0}}>
                        <li><Link to="/">Homse</Link></li>
                        <li><Link to="/bubblegum">Bubblegum</Link></li>
                        <li><Link to="/shoelaces" activeClassName="active">Shoelaces</Link></li>
                        <li><Link to="/processes" activeStyle={{ color: 'red' }}>processbbes</Link></li>
                    </ul>
                    {routes.map((route, index) => (
                        <Route
                            key={index}
                            path={route.path}
                            exact={route.exact}
                            component={route.sidebar}
                        />
                    ))}
                </div>

                <div style={{flex: 1, padding: '10px'}}>
                    {routes.map((route, index) => (
                        // Render more <Route>s with the same paths as
                        // above, but different components this time.
                        <Route
                            key={index}
                            path={route.path}
                            exact={route.exact}
                            component={route.main}
                        />
                    ))}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </Router>
), document.getElementById('root'))
```

That works fine so far.

But how do I define additonal routes in my containers  which not reload the page and not shown in the sidebar?

How can I put the const routes in an external file?

is this a practicable way of using react-router?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can move the routes const to another file if you are using something like CommmonJS or, more specifically, a compiler like Webpack.

```
# /app/routes.js
export default [
  {
    path: '/',
    exact: true,
    sidebar: () => <div>home!</div>,
    main: () => <h2>Home</h2>
  },
  ...
]{

# file above
import routes from './routes'
```

Additional routes not shown in sidebar can be called in the components rendered by any of your route objects. In this example, just make sure to have a route object that matches that path. You'd run into the issue of being on a route that is not highlighted on the sidebar though, which may make for confusing UI.

Is this a practical way to use react router? Seems flexible enough.